# Responsive Web Design Limits

Tags: html

I want my website to expand when the window is larger, and center accordingly, but when the window is shrunk I want the website to collapse until a certain point and after that point the collapse ceases.

Is there a way to set the minimum width on responsive websites?

Answer (score 3):

```
body{min-width:480px}
```

Or whatever minimum width you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

There's a css property [min-width](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/min-width) which you can certainly use.

Answer (score 0):

The added bonus of min-width is that you can set it for your main window, but also set it for each component on the page -- a sidebar, or a content block.

Each min-width/max-width can be different, so as you resize the page, those blocks will conform to their restrictions.

This makes doing a quick and dirty mobile site really simple, if all of your min-width blocks start stacking vertically, in the order you've written them in HTML (minus any floats / fixed-position blocks you have in there).